How to draw the horizontal and vertical lines for every value of x and y ticks with a specific opacity? (in the background)
x = [value for value in df['YEAR']]
y1 = [value for value in df['ANNUAL']]
y2 = [df['ANNUAL'].mean()]*(len(x))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))

plt.plot(x,y1,label='Annual rainfall',color='blue')
plt.plot(x,y2,'r--',label='Mean Rainfall')

plt.legend()
plt.show()

Desired image

I was doing a tutorial on matplotlib in python and I'm stuck at this point of designing the layout of the plot.
I am expecting the background lines on the graph using matplotlib functions.
How to insert the horizontal and vertical lines in the background?

With this, you will get the desired background grid lines with the specified opacity. You can adjust the alpha value to make the lines more or less transparent
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [value for value in df['YEAR']]
y1 = [value for value in df['ANNUAL']]
y2 = [df['ANNUAL'].mean()] * len(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))

plt.plot(x, y1, label='Annual rainfall', color='blue')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r--', label='Mean Rainfall')

plt.grid(True, which='both', axis='both', linestyle='--', color='gray', alpha=0.3)

plt.legend()

plt.show()

